# Can I connect two ViewModels without DependencyProperty?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, parent-child, viewmodel

I have MainWindow (simplified for clarity):

```
<Window>
    <!-- (...) -->

    <Window.DataContext>
         <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <!-- (...) -->

    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ShowAdvanced}" Content="Advanced view" />
    <uc:MyUserControl DataContext={Binding MyUserControlViewModel} />
</Window>
```

MainWindowViewModel:

```
public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
         MyUserControlVM = new MyUserControlViewModel();
    }

    private bool _showAdvanced;
    public bool ShowAdvanced
    {
        get => _showAdvanced;
        set { _showAdvanced = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private MyUserControlViewModel _myUserControlVM;
    public MyUserControlViewModel MyUserControlVM
    {
        get => _myUserControlVM;
        set { _myUserControlVM= value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

In my UserControl I have some controls supposed to be hidden when "Show advanced" checkbox is not checked.

```
<GroupBox Header="Some advanced stuff"
    Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.(vm:MainWindowViewModel.ShowAdvanced), Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
    <!-- (...) -->
</GroupBox>
```

This actually works, but I don't like this because UserControl relies on MainWindow.

**How can I connect these viewmodels correctly without DependencyProperty?**

I have tried to add this to MyUserControlViewModel:

```
public MyUserControlViewModel(MainWindowViewModel parent)
{
    Parent = parent;
}

private MainWindowViewModel _parent;
public MainWindowViewModel Parent
{
    get { return _parent; }
    set { _parent = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

and bind visibility on one of MyUserControl controls like this:

```
Visibility="{Binding Parent.ShowAdvanced}"
```

but this is not working (MyUserControl is not getting notified?).

Comment: Normally, binding via a path like that would work fine. I just coded a super-simple example and it updated on changes just as expected. So you have something wrong in your initialization, probably using the wrong view model instance somewhere. You'll need to fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: `ShowAdvanced` should be a property of `MyUserControlViewModel`

Comment: @PeterDuniho As I wrote - my binding with Path in XAML works. I want to get rid of this from my view (and move this relation to view models.

Comment: @SirRufo: the whole point here is that his `UserControl` view model is delegating that property to the main view model class, where the property is defined. `MyUserControlViewModel` has the `Parent` property, via which the binding path _should_ find the main view model's `ShowAdvanced` property.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I know that, but I recommend that the property **should** belong to the control VM

Comment: @Kamil: you misunderstand. `{Binding Parent.ShowAdvanced}` is a binding via a path, which is what I'm talking about. `Path` is the default property for the `{Binding}` extension, so in `{Binding Parent.ShowAdvanced}`, you are providing `"Parent.ShowAdvanced"` as the path.

Comment: @SirRufo: if you're going to make a prescriptive statement like that, you're going to have to justify it. There's no obvious reason to suggest that a property that needs to be known by two different UI objects, with two different view models, should then have to be replicated in both view models instead of just delegating from one view model to the other.

Comment: @SirRufo That property cannot belong to the control VM because I have more control like this, relying on that MainWindow checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `ShowAdvanced` property to the control VM and assign the value to each control VM whenever a new value is assigned to the `MainViewModel` `ShowAdvanced` property.

```
public class MainViewModel : Base.ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _showAdvanced;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MyUserControl1 = new MyUserControlViewModel { Message = "Control 1" };
        MyUserControl2 = new MyUserControlViewModel { Message = "Control 2" };
        MyUserControl3 = new MyUserControlViewModel { Message = "Control 3" };
    }

    public bool ShowAdvanced
    {
        get => _showAdvanced;
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged( ref _showAdvanced, value );
            MyUserControl1.ShowAdvanced = value;
            MyUserControl2.ShowAdvanced = value;
            MyUserControl3.ShowAdvanced = value;
        }
    }

    public MyUserControlViewModel MyUserControl1 { get; }
    public MyUserControlViewModel MyUserControl2 { get; }
    public MyUserControlViewModel MyUserControl3 { get; }
}

public class MyUserControlViewModel : Base.ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _showAdvanced;
    private string _message;

    public bool ShowAdvanced { get => _showAdvanced; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged( ref _showAdvanced, value ); }
    public string Message { get => _message; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged( ref _message, value ); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. There probably is no better way to do it. My mind stuck on DependencyObject magic and I thought that it is possible without "manual" value rewriting to child viewmodels. By the way - can you show your RaiseAndSetIfChanged implementation? Does it actually check if value changed with some comparer, or just fires an event even if you change "Abc" to "Abc"?

Comment: Someone voted -1... Can you explain please what is wrong with this?

Comment: @Kamil NuGet ReactiveUI.WPF ;o) - it raises the event if changed

Comment: Damn frameworks. Whenever I learn how to use one framework well, a new one appears, I start using it and I feel like a beginner again ;)